# unable to pass data between one component to another component in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components, angular-module

I am trying to pass data from one component to another component I used the service file method.
I created two components one is login and the second is home. I have to pass data from login to home.
in the login component, I take user input, and the home component should print that.
I used this code below, but when I give input, it is not printing in output.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {
  message : any;

  constructor() { }
  setMessage(data: any){
    this.message=data;
  }
  getMessage(){
    return this.message;
  }
}
```

this is my home component code

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { SharedService } from '../shared/shared.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
 message : string | undefined;

  constructor(private shared:SharedService ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
   this.message =this.shared.getMessage()
} 
}
```

```html
<h1> {{ message }} </h1>
```

this is my login component code

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { SharedService } from "../shared/shared.service"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  message : any ;

  constructor(
    private  shared: SharedService
  ) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.shared.setMessage(this.message)
  }

}
```

```html
    <input required type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter username" [(ngModel)]="message">
```

Comment: Looking the code, seems like you're setting the message in your service inside `ngOnInit` in your `Login` component. This way you are setting the value only when the component is initialized, not updating the service when user type something, so the value will be undefined. **I think it is necessary to set the message, at the submit of the login, just before navigating to the `Home`.**

Comment: hey thanks for responding to me. I used your suggestions and really it's working for me

Answer (score 0):

ofcourse it will not work this way .the reason it is not working . when you call SharedService in your constructor in box component it create an instance of your service with  message : any . if you change it on one component it will not change on the other component .

what you can do is .
on your service . `message = new Subject() ;  setMessage(data: any){ this.message.next(data) ; }`
you call set message on your login component . and on your home component you subscribe to the subject like this . `this.sharedService.getMessage().subscribe( (result :any ) => {console.log(result )}`  .

sorry if this answer is messy , this is my first time using SOF .

Comment: hey thanks for replaying. i get answer in my comment and I will also try your suggestions also

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).